# Django FileField: How to return filename only (in template)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-file-upload

I've got a field in my model of type [`FileField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield). This gives me an object of type [`File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/files/file/), which has the following method:

> `File.name`: The name of the file including the relative path from
>   `MEDIA_ROOT`.

What I want is something like "`.filename`" that will only give me the filename and not the path as well, something like:

```html
{% for download in downloads %}
  <div class="download">
    <div class="title">{{download.file.filename}}</div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Which would give something like `myfile.jpg`

Answer (score 230, accepted):

In your model definition:

```
import os

class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    ...

    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

Comment: worked great but needed the param to be passed into basename as self.file.name.  I think it needs this as self.file is a file object rather than the string to the file.

Comment: adding the @property decorator avoids calling file.filename() and simply file.filename can be used

Comment: Surprisingly this solution even works with `S3` storage backend.

Comment: It works for me. Could you please some information to explain how it works?

Comment: @user3327344 Which is the part that you have trouble with?

Answer (score 60):

You can do this by creating a template filter:

In `myapp/templatetags/filename.py`:

```
import os

from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def filename(value):
    return os.path.basename(value.file.name)
```

And then in your template:

```
{% load filename %}

{# ... #}

{% for download in downloads %}
  <div class="download">
      <div class="title">{{download.file|filename}}</div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is also a nice approach. Perhaps a little more portable?

Comment: As you wrote the filter it should be {{download|filename}}

Comment: don’t forget the `__init__.py` file to ensure the templatetags directory is treated as a Python package.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the [`cut` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#cut) in your template

```
{% for download in downloads %}
  <div class="download">
    <div class="title">{{download.file.filename|cut:'remove/trailing/dirs/'}}</div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

A modern solution using Pathlib:

```py
from pathlib import Path

class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    ...

    def filename(self):
        return Path(self.file.name).name
```

Answer (score -3):

You can access the filename from the file field object with the name property.

```
class CsvJob(Models.model):

    file = models.FileField()
```

then you can get the particular objects filename using.

```
obj = CsvJob.objects.get()
obj.file.name property
```

Comment: Accessing `obj.file.name` returns the entire path in the media dir, e.g. it returns `tasks/132/foo.jpg` rather than `foo.jpg`.