# Substring with split in html template django python

Tags: python, django

I have this model:

```
def generate_filename(self, filename):
    url = "files/users/%s/%s" % (self.user.id, filename)
    return url

class Upload(models.Model):
    user = modelo.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    docfile = modelo.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)
```

Views.py

```
allfiles = Upload.objects.all()
```

I have a list of uploaded files in django:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in allfiles %}
        <li><a href="{{ item.docfile.url }}">{{ item.docfile.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Its showing on html the full path of my file:

```
files/users/1/test.txt
```

I want to show only `test.txt`

I tryed this:

```
<ul>
    {% for item in arquivos %}
        <li><a href="{{ item.docfile.url }}">{{ item.docfile.name.split('/')[3] }}</a></a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

but I got `Could not parse the remainder: '('/')' from 'item.docfile.name.split('/')[3]'`

**EDIT**

I tryed to create a file in `myapp/templatetags/filename.py`:

```
import os

from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def filename(value):
    return os.path.basename(value.docfile.name)
```

In template:

```
{% load filename %}
<ul>
    {% for item in allfiles %}
        <li><a href="{{ item.docfile.url }}">{{ item.docfile|filename }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And now I'm getting this:

```
'filename' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
filaname
future
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz
```

Comment: You can't use raw python in a django template...

Comment: i'm sorry sayse, i'm kinda new in django.... can you be a little more specific or show some examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django filefield return filename only in template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683621/django-filefield-return-filename-only-in-template)

Comment: I'm just trying to solve this without changing my model... :(

Comment: Then scroll down in the duplicate. although the selected answer doesn't change the model, it adds a method to it.

Comment: Just tryed this now...edited my question.. didnt work :(

Comment: check my answer now, i hopw it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me i will prefer you make a function inside your model that will do this for you

```
import os

class Upload(models.Model):
    user = modelo.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    docfile = modelo.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)

    def get_docfile_name(self):
        if not self.docfile:
            return ""
        file_path = self.docfile.name
        return os.path.basename(file_path)
```

in your template

```
<ul>
{% for item in allfiles %}
    <li><a href="{{ item.docfile.url }}">{{ item.get_docfile_name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```