# Python Django Template cannot get name from model function

Tags: python, django, file, filefield

While I understood that I can call a function definition from our models, I can't seem to extract the file name of my uploaded document. Below I tried the following template format but either results from my desired output:

***.html Version 1***

```
<form action="." method="GET">
{% if documents %}
   <ul>
      {% for document in documents %}
        <li> {{ document.docfile.filename }}
        <input type = "submit" name="load-data" value="Add to Layer"/>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

*Result: It just shows the button.*

***.html Version 2***

```
<form action="." method="GET">
{% if documents %}
   <ul>
      {% for document in documents %}
        <li> {{ document.filename }}
        <input type = "submit" name="load-data" value="Add to Layer"/>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

*Result: It just shows the button.*

***.html Version 3***

```
<form action="." method="GET">
{% if documents %}
   <ul>
      {% for document in documents %}
        <li> {{ document.docfile.name }}
        <input type = "submit" name="load-data" value="Add to Layer"/>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

*Result: Prints the complete pathname (eg: /documents/2016/10/08/filename.csv) together with the button*

Here's the rest of my code:

***models.py***

```
class Document(models.Model):
     docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='document/%Y/%m/%d')

     def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

***views.py***

```
documents = Document.objects.all()
return render(request, 'gridlock/upload-data.html',
              {
               'documents' : documents,
               'form': form
              })
```

I hope someone can explain why everything I tried:
`{{ document.docfile.filename }}` or `{{document.file.filename}}` or `{{document.filename}}` won't work either for me? Thanks!

Comment: A better approach is to create `template tag` instead of editing models. Check the [SO Post][1] from the above answer. You will find an answer on creating template tag.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683621/django-filefield-return-filename-only-in-template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you got pretty close with `{{ document.filename }}`, except in your models you need to change

```
def filename(self):
    return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

into

```
def filename(self):
    # try printing the filename here to see if it works
    print (os.path.basename(self.docfile.name))
    return os.path.basename(self.docfile.name)
```

in your models the field is called docfile, so you need to use self.docfile to get its value.

source: [django filefield return filename only in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2683621/django-filefield-return-filename-only-in-template)

Comment: thanks! this is the correct answer! I'll read up the reference you just linked!

Comment: ohhh I get it now. that was what confused me under models! thanks again!